# Arch: Candy Icons not working properly-

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, icons

I'm new to Arch btw. I'm using it on a VirtualBox with XFCE as a Desktop Environment. So,  recently installed candy icons  but not get them to work properly.In my user directory, only the icon for Desktop folder is applied. Other folder icons are not applied. Is it the icon set specific thing or something wrong with my configuration. I put my icons in `~/.icons/Candy-Icons`. What to do??

Candy-Icons: https://github.com/EliverLara/candy-icons
[image]

Comment: If you got the icons from gnome-look, you should check and verify that the icon pack is compatible with your DE and its version. To troubleshoot, you could try to install a different icon pack and see if that works. If it works, it is most likely a problem with the other icon pack.

Comment: I just cloned this repo into ~/.icons/ directory, and icons get listed in appearance settings. I also updated the fonts icons cache.

Comment: Did you clone it directly into the `.icons` folder?

Comment: I cloned into downloads, then copy-pasted into .icons folder. Does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch back to the default theme.
2. Remove the icon pack from `~/.icons`.
3. [Go to the icons' opendesktop page](https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1305251/) and click on 'Files' and download the icon pack from there.
4. Unpack the newly downloaded files, and move the resulting folder to `~/.icons`. Be sure to check that the unpacked folder doesn't contain another subdir; if it does, move the subdir to the `~/.icons` directory.
5. Switch to the new theme.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your fixes would work if my user directory was set up correctly. Apparently, when I installed arch and made a user account, it did not set up my user directory correctly. I thought that should not cause any issues, but as you see, it did indeed. So i installed xdg-user-dirs https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_user_directories. $ xdg-user-dirs-update did the work!